# Angular 2 ng2-logger custom colors configuration

Tags: angular

I have installed `ng2-logger` in order to visualize better my console.logs.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-logger

But, the colors are random.

Is it a way that I could choose a color of my preference for each component or file type? If so, how could it be done? 
My goal is to have some sort of configuration for `ng2-logger` without having to type the color on each instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Try creating a vector for your log configuration, such as:

```
export const LOG_CONFIG: any = {
    app: '#2d2a26',
    filter: '#2e6991',
    table: '#a8353a',
    service: '#ae6d36',
    navigation: '#014822'
};
```

And then just call it this way in your file:

```
import { Log } from 'ng2-logger';
import { LOG_CONFIG } from 'path/log_config';

const log = Log.create('Table's Component);
log.color = LOG_CONFIG.table;
```

This way, you instance your `Log` with a color for each type of file or Component.

In my example I just did it with color, you could do it with text, Level and other `ng2-logger` options.

I hope it helped!

Cheers! ;)

Comment: I'm using the same log library! :D

Comment: Thanx! That's what I was looking for ;)